# create table based on database with empty cells

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a database which contain data and on which table column should this data be in and the other column should be empty

```
 =====================
|   data   |  column  |
 =====================
|  orange  |    1     |
|  apple   |    2     |
|  banana  |    6     |
 =====================

for($i = 1;$i <= 7;$i++) {  
$stmt->fetch(); 
echo ($i == $column ? '<td>' . $data . '</td>' : '<td></td>');
}

Output:
 =========================================================
|   1    |   2   |   3   |   4   |   5   |   6    |   7   |
=========================================================
| orange | apple |       |       |       | banana |       |
 =========================================================
```

So far, so good and all rows with column 1 filled is working fine

BUT!!!

```
 =====================
|   data   |  column  |
 =====================
|  orange  |    3     |
|  apple   |    4     |
|  banana  |    5     |
 =====================

for($i = 1;$i <= 7;$i++) {  
$stmt->fetch(); 
echo ($i == $column ? '<td>' . $data . '</td>' : '<td></td>');
}

Output:
 ========================================================
|   1   |   2   |   3   |   4   |    5   |   6   |   7   |
=========================================================
|       |       |       |       | banana |       |       |
 ========================================================
```

and all rows with column one is empty are not working properly !!!

also i want to repeat this multiple times

```
 =============================================================
|   1    |    2   |   3    |   4   |    5   |    6   |  7     |
 =============================================================
| orange |  apple |        |       |        | banana |        |
 =============================================================
|        |        | orange | apple | banana |        |        |
 ============================================================= 
|        | orange |        | apple |        |        | banana |
 =============================================================
```

thank you for you helping

**edit**

the complete code:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT  column, data FROM fruits";

if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($column, $data);

?>

<table border="1" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #000000;color:#000000;width:100%; text-align: center; vertical-align: center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

<?php   

for($i = 1;$i <= 7;$i++) {

    $stmt->fetch(); 
    echo ($i == $column ? '<td>' . $data . '</td>' : '<td></td>');
    }

    $stmt->close();

    } else {
        echo $conn->error;
    }

$conn->close();

?>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you please show your complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 /* prepare statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
$stmt->execute();

/* bind variables to prepared statement */
$stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2);

/* fetch values */
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
   $myarray[$col1]=$col2;
}
for ($i=1; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    if(array_key_exists($i, $myarray)){
      echo '<td>'. $myarray[$i] .'</td>';
    }else{
      echo '<td></td>';
    }
}
/* close statement */
$stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: its worked great thank you but how can I make multiple rows such as my last example ?